# ManagementObjectSearcher ProcessorId = null

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Hey i trying to get ProccessorId from ManagementObjectSearcher. It work's fine for me, but when i give my software to a friend it gives me System.NullReferenceException.

```
var mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_processor");
var mbsList = mbs.Get();
var id = "";
foreach (var mo in mbsList)
    id = mo["ProcessorID"].ToString();
return id;
```

So i serialize mo object to json and saw that ProcessorId value is null.    `{"Name":"ProcessorId","Value":null,"Type":8,"IsLocal":false,"IsArray":false,"Origin":"Win32_Processor","Qualifiers":[{"Name":"CIMTYPE","Value":"string","IsAmended":false,"IsLocal":false,"PropagatesToInstance":true,"PropagatesToSubclass":true,"IsOverridable":true}]}`

I just don't understand why that happens.
Any other ways to get ProcessorId or maybe there are fixes for this? I need that to generate HWID of system.

P.S.
My friend don't use virtual mashine.

Answer (score 0):

Yea most processors are not returning a value, some think that it could have been used to get some software copy protection. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b515a58a-c2b1-497f-a539-19b76b1828f4/processorid-is-null-management-class?forum=csharpgeneral